# Why doesn't Jupyter notebook link show properly?

Tags: python, jupyter

In the Jupyter notebook on a Markdown cell the following code is supposed to display the word "Github" as a link and nothing else:

```
[Github] (http://www.github.com/)
```

In other words, http://www.github.com/ should disappear, leaving only the word Github in the cell, which should work as a link to the URL (at least that is how I understand it).

Instead, after execution I get exactly the code above with slightly different formatting as http://www.github.com/ becomes a link.

What am I missing?

Comment: There should be no space between `](` - so `[Github](http://www.github.com/)` is the correct way.

Comment: @cel - Thanks. It worked.